# Sqlite database locked when executing "END"

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios

In order to speed up my DB insertions on an Sqlite3 DB on iOS6, I'm wrapping the inserts in "BEGIN" and "END" commands. 
The DB is set to run in serialized  mode. 
The interesting thing is that I'm getting an exception when executing the "END": the error says the DB is locked. 
Well, I expect it to be locked, after all I'm in a transaction as far as I can tell. 
Can somebody explain what conditions could cause this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. To make serialized access work, you may have only one connection. In my test project I forgot to implement the connection cache. This way I ended up with quite many (open) connections for each database.

Answer (score 0):

It's got to be something simple, as there's nothing fancy about BEGIN/END commands. I tried hard to reproduce your problem (eliminating `sqlite3_finalize`, eliminate `BEGIN`, etc.) but I couldn't. The only way I know to generate that error is to open the database multiple times or doing something with background queues.

You'll have to share source code with us. Perhaps you're attempting to reopen the database? Or do you have something on a background queue that could be holding it? Etc.

You mention opening the database in serial mode. Do I infer from that you have multiple queues/threads doing database operations? I personally serialize my database operations by having a serial queue to which I dispatch my database calls, which guarantees serial operations, and thus I never have to worry about opening the database in a particular mode. Maybe you can describe the rationale for opening the database in serial mode.

But, anyway, here's a sample insert method using the `sqlite` calls directly (though I admit that I usually use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) to eliminate ugly code like this):

```
- (void)sqlInsert
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    sqlite3 *database = NULL;
    int rc;
    char *errmsg;

    if ((rc = [self openDatabase:&database]) != SQLITE_OK) // my open does the necessary parsing of the path, copying files, etc.
    {
        NSLog(@"%s database open error %d", __FUNCTION__, rc);
        return;
    }

    sqlite3_exec(database, "BEGIN", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    if (errmsg != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s exec BEGIN SQL error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, errmsg);
        sqlite3_free(errmsg);
    }

    const char *insertSql = "INSERT INTO CONTACTS (name, address, phone) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";

    if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, insertSql, -1, &statement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s prepare SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, [self.contactName.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s bind contactName error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 2, [self.contactAddress.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s bind contactAddress error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 3, [self.contactPhone.text UTF8String], -1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSLog(@"%s bind contactPhone error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        NSLog(@"%s Contact added", __FUNCTION__);
    else
        NSLog(@"%s step SQL error '%s' (%1d)", __FUNCTION__, sqlite3_errmsg(database), sqlite3_errcode(database));

    sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    sqlite3_exec(database, "END", NULL, NULL, &errmsg);
    if (errmsg != NULL)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s exec END SQL error '%s'", __FUNCTION__, errmsg);
        sqlite3_free(errmsg);
    }        

    sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

Comment: I have indeed multiple threads. But at that particular moment, there is only one thread active. Hence the serialized mode. I'm also sharing the same connection all over, otherwise the serialization wouldn't work. I tested the serialization by hammering the DB with various threads and it is bullet proof. If I switch to default mode, it fails as expected. I have been running this code for a long time and today it started hanging, so I was wondering if there is an obvious thing in Sqlite that can cause this problem. Looks like I'll have to dig deeper.

Comment: @Krumelur Yeah, if you hammer from different threads without either (a) having a dedicated queue for database operations; or (b) using serialized mode, you'd have problems. I was just wondering, though, if you were relying upon the database's serialized mode, were the three separate calls, `begin`, `insert`, and `end`, being treated as three separate statements that could be serialized with other database calls from other threads (bad). If you're only using one thread at the moment, then that's not the problem. But by having a dedicated queue for database operations, this issue goes away.