# it can't be working in inserting database

Tags: ios5, sqlite, xcode4.5

here I optimize following code I got perfect upto the database path means NSLog(@"in save data::%s",dbasePath); but after that can't be optimize if condition code

```
-(void)saveData{
    sqlite3_stmt *statment;
    dirPath=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir=[dirPath objectAtIndex:0];
    const char *dbasePath=[dbPath UTF8String];
    NSLog(@"in save data::%s",dbasePath);

    if (sqlite3_open(dbasePath, &sqlDatabase)) {
        NSString *insert_query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO PRJDATA VALUES(\"%@\",\"%@\"\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\",\"%@\")",title,timeGet1.text,timeGet2.text,timeGet3.text,dateField.text,interval1.text,interval2.text];
        NSLog(@"query string::%@",insert_query);
        const char *insert_stmt=[insert_query UTF8String];
        NSLog(@"error in insert::%s",sqlite3_errmsg(sqlDatabase));
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(sqlDatabase, insert_stmt, -1, &statment, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statment)==SQLITE_DONE) {
            status.text=@"content added";
            timeGet1.text=@"";
            timeGet2.text=@"";
            timeGet3.text=@"";
            dateField.text=@"";
            interval1.text=@"";
            interval2.text=@"";

        }
        else{
            status.text=@"failed to add";
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(statment);
        sqlite3_close(sqlDatabase);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple of thoughts:

1. Why set `dirPath` and `docsDir` if your `dbasePath` doesn't use them? That's uses `dbPath`, which you presumably meant to define based upon `docsDir`, but you don't define anywhere here.
2. Also, can you show us your `NSLog` results from your code sample? Just update your question accordingly. No point in doing `NSLog` but not sharing that with us.
3. As I suggested in my other answer, whenever you get an error, show the `sqlite3_errmsg`, as that will tell you what went wrong. Why guess when you can have SQLite tell you what's wrong? You'll drive yourself nuts if you don't show `sqlite3_errmsg` results.
4. Do your `VALUES` in your `INSERT` statement reflect all of the columns of the table? If not, you should alter your `INSERT` statement to include the names of the columns that correspond to your values, e.g.

   > ```
   > INSERT INTO TABLE1 (COL1, COL2, COL3) VALUES ("VALUE1", "VALUE2", "VALUE3");
   > ```
5. You really should not be building your `INSERT` string using `stringWithFormat`. You should use `?` placeholders and then use `sqlite3_bind_` functions. See [Sqlite database locked when executing "END"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13629290/sqlite-database-locked-when-executing-end/13632096#13632096) for an example of `sqlite3_bind` functions (ignore the question, but just look at the `sqlite3_bind` statements in the code sample). This saves you from having to deal with weird exceptions like what if the `title` field had double quotes in it ... that would break your current routine. It also protects you against SQL injection attacks. It's just prudent.